# moviepy, after a few seconds the video freeze

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, ffmpeg, pip, moviepy

I have an issue with the compressing the videos.
The following code should resize the video and compress it:

```
import moviepy.editor as mp
def video_compressor(input_path):
    if input_path is not None:        
        base_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(input_path))[0]        
        output_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(input_path), base_name + ".mp4")
        print(f"Input path: {input_path}")
        print(f"Output path: {output_path}")
        clip = mp.VideoFileClip(input_path)        
        new_height = 360
        new_width = int(clip.w * (new_height / clip.h))        
        new_width = new_width if new_width % 2 == 0 else new_width - 1
        new_height = new_height if new_height % 2 == 0 else new_height - 1
        clip_resized = clip.resize(newsize=(new_width, new_height))
        clip_resized.write_videofile(output_path, codec="libx264", threads=1,
                                     ffmpeg_params=['-profile:v', 'baseline', '-level', '3.0',
                                                    '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', '-acodec', 'aac'])

        return output_path
```

It works well on my local machine with conda environment. But doesn't work on EC2 Ubuntu where I'm using pip Virtual Environment.

I assume that the different is that conda environment consists ffmpeg 4.3.1. But pip Virtual environment does not. I've made a Symbolic Link to FFmpeg in my Virtual Environment, but the output file still contains of full audio and a few seconds of video and then it freeze.

Maybe someone had such a problem? Please share your experienceю

I tried to make it on my local PC with conda environment and all is OK. I assume that I can't understand the way of using FFmpeg with pip Virtual Environment.

Answer (score 2):

Solved an issue. The problem was that I've tried to safe compressed file with the same name as the original one.
So if you'll get that problem - just make sure that your input and output files have different names.